# Where Auto Summarize Tool In Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have been able to fine directions for finding and adding auto summarize in Word 2007, however I cannot find it anywhere in the docs or online. Please advise!

Answer (score 1):

It is peculiar that your question is verbatim to [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/how-do-i-find-the-auto-summarize-feature-in-word/522a8e3b-84af-4720-8397-826a97d2c1ed) on Microsoft Answers. To summarize the discussion over there, the **AutoSummary** feature was [removed](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179199.aspx#BKMK_Remmoved) in Word 2010.

> AutoSummary is the feature that lists the Title, Subject, Author,
>   Keywords, and Comments. This feature was available from the Tools
>   menu. In Word 2010, this feature is no longer used. If you insert an
>   abstract into the document, that is not AutoSummary data and will
>   remain. However, if the document was in a summary view when it is
>   saved, it will not be after you open it.